# How can I use Mighty Mouse Swipe Gestures for Back/Forth in Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, multi-touch, history, mouse

I have the latest mighty mouse bluetooth wireless thing. (Hate it.)

In Mac App Store, I'd wish to be able to swipe left and right to be able to go back and forth, such as in Safari, Chrome, etc.

How can I achieve this? Preferably by native/OS means, without resorting to 3rd party solutions (BetterTouchTool, etc).

Comment: If you're using gestures, then I believe what you actually have is the latest "Magic Mouse" bluetooth wireless thing.  If you do in fact have a Mighty Mouse, then that would be the root of your problem, as they don't support gestures.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the native Magic Mouse preferences pane is a little sparse.  As far as I can tell, unless you are willing to move to a 3rd party solution, the Magic Mouse does not support the behavior you are looking for.  In order to enable this functionality on an Apple trackpad, one must change the preference from 2 finger swipe to 3 finger swipe ("2 or 3" finger works as well).  It should be noted though, that even when enabled, in apps without the fancy page sliding across the screen animation, the swiping *does not* follow the "Natural Scrolling" paradigm, as in you must swipe left to go back and right to go forwarded.

While not the answer you were hoping for, it sounds like your best bet would be to either investigate a 3rd party option like [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) or even better, invest in a Magic Trackpad.  The gesture options, even natively are greatly expanded.  It will open up a whole new world of gesture based computing for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I find it very disappointing/confusing, that there is a setting in System Preferences for scrolling pages back and forth with one finger (which works perfectly in Safari). I can't see how Apple can't implement this nice feature in one of their own programs, to provide some consistency. As it is now, I have to mouse up to the Back and Forward buttons (!) to navigate.